# Create a function that returns a list containing every other value of a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun f6(x)
    (cond
        ((null (cadr x)) '())
        (T (cons (car x) (f6 (cdr (cadr x)))))
    )
        

)
```

```
;Example input:
;(c (a b) d (x y) (a) b))
;Expected output:
;(c d (a))
;Current ouput:
;(C . B)
```

In creating this function I can't use built in loops it must be recursive I cannot use setQ or any every-other function either. So I need to use car cdr and cadr. I really don't know where the period is coming from and why its reading list (a b) as an atom when in other instances I've used recursion on lists it's been able to distinguish.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is invalid, because it calls some undefined function `f5`. If I replace `f5` with `f6` and call `(f6 '(c (a b) d (x y) (a) b))`, it returns `(C)`. So, you need to use different combination of [accessors](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_car_c.htm).

```
(defun every-other (lst)
  (if (null lst) '()
    (cons (car lst)
          (every-other (cddr lst)))))

(every-other '(c (a b) d (x y) (a) b))
```

`(cddr lst)` is `(cdr (cdr lst))`.